# How to add Organic Groups after Site has been created

Tags: 7, organic-groups

My site allows people from a certain class to upload their pictures on the website. It has various content types and views made but and I would like to install the Organic Groups module to allow multiple classes from my school to upload images.
Can I do that now or do I need to re-create the site from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to re-create the whole site from scratch. After installing Organic Groups, you can mark an existing content type as "Group Content" if you want the nodes of that type to belong to a group:

- Go to `admin/structure/types`.
- Click on the "Edit" link next to the type you want to modify.
- In the `Organic groups` tab, check the `Group content` checkbox. It will create a `Groups audience` field in your content type.

After that, you will need to assign each node to the appropriate group, in the `Groups audience` field.